# downgrade PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.0

Tags: php, nginx, php7

I've a Ubuntu 16.04 server running nginx + PHP7.1.2. I have a PHP script that is executed by a cronjob, it's giving some compatibilities issues (in PHP 7.0 it works perfectly and other people had the same issue), so, right now I need to downgrade the version of PHP to 7.0.14 (I think that maybe the CLI version?). So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can disable php7.1 service

> sudo a2dismod php7.1

and enable service php of which ever version you want

> sudo a2enmod php5.6

then restart your apache

> sudo service apache2 restart

This will not uninstall the php7.1 but you can work with downgraded version without error